# How to state it as day or evening from sunrise and sunset timings?

Tags: reactjs

From some api I'am getting the sunrise and sunset timings as 06:42 and 17:57 respectively. When the time is greater or equal to 06:42 it must display 'DAY' and when greater than or equal to 17:57 must display 'EVENING'.How to do it?

App.js

```
fetch(`${IP_LOCATION}&lat=${lat}&long=${lon}`)
  .then(res => res.json()).then(responseJson => {
    console.log('DATA', responseJson)
    try {
      this.setState({
        sunrise: responseJson.sunrise,
        sunset: responseJson.sunset,
      })

    } catch {
      toast.error('No Data Received')
    }

  });


render() {
      return (
        {console.log('sunrise', this.state.sunrise)}// returns 06:42
        {console.log('sunset', this.state.sunset)}// returns 17:57
        // How to display DAY and EVENING/NIGHT
)
} 

export default App
```

As seen above, I get the sunrise and sunset values.

Comment: what have you tried so far? start with parsing the time, and comparing it with the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first get sunrise and sunset as a JavaScript `Date` object.

```
const sunrise = new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + this.state.sunrise); 
const sunset = new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + this.state.sunset);
```

Now, let's get the current data and do our check!

```
const now = new Date();
const isLightOut = now > sunrise && now < sunset;
```

Of course, in terms of React, we can now use our `isLightOut` variable to render the text, as needed:

```
render() {
  return isLightOut ? "DAY" : "NIGHT";
}
```